# Ionic 4: How to add zoom in and out using native qr scanner?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, native, qr-code, barcode-scanner

How can I implement zoom functionality in a native qr scanner? I tried installing the camera preview plugin but it keeps crashing the app. The new versions probably do not support it. My project version:

> Ionic:
>
> Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.5(C:\Users\Ivo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
>
> Ionic Framework               :
>   @ionic/angular                : 4.11.5
>   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
>   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
>   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
>   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1
>
> Cordova:
>
> Cordova CLI                  : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
>    Cordova Platforms            : not available
>    Cordova Plugins              : not available
>
> Utility:
>
> cordova-res : 0.8.1
>      native-run  : 0.2.9
>
> System:
>
> Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\Ivo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
>      NodeJS            : v10.11.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
>      npm               : 6.9.0
>      OS                : Windows 10

I have tried so far:

- to install camera preview plugin but it is not supported by this ionic version
- searched for a QRScanner method, but wasn't able to find one. Found methods only for flashlight and rotating camera.

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you've tried

Comment: Added with bullet points. There is no information on the internet on this topic